# MYSQL pivot with three tables returns NULL

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many

Search didn't give any result, because there's no way to make question less vague.
I've a db like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'john'),
    (2, 'jane'),
    (3, 'max')
;

CREATE TABLE agents
    (`id` int, `title` varchar(25))
;

INSERT INTO agents
    (`id`, `title`)
VALUES
    (1, 'APERTURE'),
    (2, 'MESA')
;

CREATE TABLE pivot
    (`contractid` int, `userid` varchar(4), `agentid` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO pivot
    (`contractid`, `userid`, `agentid`)
VALUES
    (1, '1', '1'),
    (1, '2', NULL),
    (2, NULL, '1'),
    (2, '2', NULL)
;

CREATE TABLE contracts
    (`id` int, `number` varchar(3), `restricted` int)
;

INSERT INTO contracts
    (`id`, `number`, `restricted`)
VALUES
    (1, 'one', 1),
    (2, 'two', 0)
;
```

and when i make such query:

```
select contracts.*, agents.title from pivot
left join users on pivot.userid = users.id
left join agents on pivot.agentid = agents.id
left join contracts on pivot.contractid = contracts.id
where users.id = 2
```

it returns

```
ID| NUMBER  |RESTRICTED|    TITLE|

1 | one     |     1    |   (null)|

2 | two     |   0      |   (null)|
```

I do understand that its because of incorrect joining and NULL is returned because in pivot table in row where userid is 2 -> agentid is NULL.

How to make a query in such way that it does correct search and returns all data required.
Many to many thanks!

edit: i want the same result as with such query

```
select contracts.*, users.id, agents.title from contracts
left join pivot on contracts.id = pivot.contractid
left join agents on pivot.agentid = agents.id
left join users on pivot.userid = users.id

where pivot.contractid in (
  select pivot.contractid from pivot where pivot.userid = 2
)
```

which will return

```
ID  NUMBER  RESTRICTED  TITLE
1   one        1       APERTURE
1   one        1       (null)
2   two        0       APERTURE
2   two        0       (null)
```

but in manner of query high above (because it queries from result of script and i cant use provided query (where in))

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to obtain from SQL query? This seems correct.. but I dont understand what would you like to obtain ..

after using filter on USER_ID = 2 in WHERE clause, you will obtain only rows, where user_id = 2 in pivot is TRUE :) so you obtain two rows with AGENT_ID is NULL ... it seems ok .. if you want to see TITLE, you should add it in table "PIVOT"

afteredit:

```
select c.*
, u.id
, a.title
##
from pivot p
##
left join contracts c
ON c.id = p.contractid
##
left join agents a
on p.agentid = a.id
##
left join users u
on p.userid = u.id
##
where 1=1
```

this gives me the same result as your query

Comment: sir, take a look at my question after edit. Any ideas?